# Passing multiple JS variables to php for mysql-insertion, though no entries are being made

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

At the end of a Javascript function that is being called when the user fills out a survey, three variables are being set. I now want to take these three variables and fill them into a MySQL database, that is running on localhost through XAMPP. My project is in the htdocs folder of XAMPP. I have tried the AJAX-approach with jQuery and I have also tried this function inside my JS:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
    {
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }

   data = "uni_id="+variable1+"&additiv="+variable2+"&konventionell="+variable3;
   xmlhttp.open("POST","speicherung.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
```

The inside of my speicherung.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "survey_data";
if(isset($_POST)){
    $uni_id = $_POST['uni_id'];
    $additiv = $_POST['additiv'];
    $konventionell = $_POST['konventionell'];}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO result_data (uni_id,additiv,konventionell,data_js)
VALUES ('$uni_id', '$additiv', '$konventionell', '0')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Unfortunately, when I execute the JS, it is not inserting anything into my MySQL table. What could I change to properly hand over the JS variables into my database so that I can access them from html at any given time later on?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you get any errors? First thing I see is `data = "uni_id="+variable1+"&additiv="+variable2+"&konventionell"+variable3;`. I would expect `"&konventionell="`, including the `=` at the end like with the other values. Second thing I see: I would expect getting the values on the PHP side with `$_POST['uni_id'];` instead of `$_POST['variable1'];` and so on since that's the name you use when constructing the data.

Comment: Edited the code as above, still don't get any entries

Comment: The php file is working properly, is just doesn't seem to get the input from JS

Comment: Do you see the POST request happening in the network tab? If so, what's the response? If not, show the code that actually calls `loadXMLDoc()`.  When I copy paste your function `loadXMLDoc()` into a page and host the page on my web server, I can see the request happening, so I doubt it's the loadXMLDoc() code that has issues unless you call it wrong or something. You Are hosting the page on the XAMPP right? Since we'll get an Access Denied error if we run it from a hard disk. But then you'd have seen that error in the console.

Comment: I assume that the forwarding from js to php is the part that is not working. I have the js script in a separate js-file and not embedded into html. It seems it is not calling the php file properly somehow

Comment: Then show the code calling `loadXMLDoc()`. the function loadXMLDoc() itself works for me, so the issue is likely somewhere else in the surrounding code if you don't see the request happening.

Comment: Yes, I see the function being called. I have now switched to AXAJ and GET just for simpler debugging, and it tells me that it is calling speicherung.php?h=123456 as I set my variable to h and a fixed value for testing purposes. But it also gives me status 404

Comment: I got it! It needed the complete path "http://localhost/folder/speicherung.php" even though the php was in the same file as the js. However the apache was running on a different port than my visual studio code live server! It's working now like a charm! Thanks for your help